# How to log in messenger with http requests

Tags: facebook, kotlin, messenger, ktor

I tried using the ktor framework for kotlin with the skrape it library to attempt to log in to facebook messenger with no success, all the libraries I can find on github are deprecated and all the past stackoverflow questions about it don't seem to work anymore. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? This is what I have tried, the output is always: "userID: null"

```
const val baseUrl = "https://www.messenger.com"

val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
        expectSuccess = false
        install(HttpCookies)
        install(DefaultRequest) {
            header("Origin", baseUrl)
            header("Referer", "$baseUrl/")
            header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9")
            header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36")
            port = 443
        }
        followRedirects = true
    }
    
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        runBlocking {
            var jazoest: String = ""
            var lsd: String = ""
            var initialRequestId: String = ""
            val timezone: String = "-120"
            val lgndim: String = "eyJ3IjoxNDQwLCJoIjo5MDAsImF3IjoxNDQwLCJhaCI6OTAwLCJjIjoyNH0%3D"
            var lgnrnd: String = ""
            var lgnjs: String = ""
            val login: String = "1"
            val persistent: String = "1"
            skrape(BrowserFetcher) {
                request {
                    url = baseUrl
                    followRedirects = true
                    headers = mapOf("Origin" to baseUrl, "Referer" to "$baseUrl/", "Accept-Language" to "en-US,en;q=0.9")
                    userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36 Edg/99.0.100.0"
                    println("user-agent: $userAgent")
                }
                response {
                    htmlDocument {
                        jazoest = input {
                            withAttribute = "name" to "jazoest"
                            findFirst {
                                attributes["value"]
                            } ?: ""
                        }
                        lsd = input {
                            withAttribute = "name" to "lsd"
                            findFirst {
                                attributes["value"]
                            } ?: ""
                        }
                        initialRequestId = input {
                            withAttribute = "name" to "initial_request_id"
                            findFirst {
                                attributes["value"]
                            } ?: ""
                        }
                        lgnrnd = input {
                            withAttribute = "name" to "lgnrnd"
                            findFirst {
                                attributes["value"]
                            } ?: ""
                        }
                        lgnjs = input {
                            withAttribute = "name" to "lgnjs"
                            findFirst {
                                attributes["value"]
                            } ?: ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            val loginPostRequest = client.post("$baseUrl/login/password/") {
                setBody(
                    "jazoest=$jazoest" +
                    "&lsd=$lsd" +
                    "&initial_request_id=$initialRequestId" +
                    "&timezone=-$timezone" +
                    "&lgndim=$lgndim" +
                    "&lgnrnd=$lgnrnd" +
                    "&lgnjs=$lgnjs" +
                    "&email=$email" +
                    "&pass=$password" +
                    "&login=$login" +
                    "&persistent=$persistent" +
                    "&default_persistent="
                )
            }
            val messengerLoggedInGetRequest = client.get(baseUrl)
            val userID = client.cookies("https://messenger.com")["c_user"]
            println("userID: $userID")
        }
        client.close()
    }
```

Comment: Be aware that Facebook doesn't allow it. So when you get banned you know why.

Comment: I suggest making the same requests with `curl` to see what responses you get and then try to figure out what is wrong with the configuration of the Ktor client.